# Use search box in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, global-variables

I'm trying to take an input in a search box and use that value as a paramether for another function, but every time I click button, when page refreshes, global variable resets itself.

This is what I have in my javascript code:

```
var searchTags;

function DoSearch()
{
    searchTags = $('#squery').val();
}

dataservices.pictureFeedService.searchForPictures(searchTags, function (data) {
    dataservices.picturesLayoutService.buildPicturesLayout("images", data);
});
```

And html code for my search box in my index is next:

```
<form id="custom-search-form" class="form-search form-horizontal">
      <div class="input-append span2 offset5">
           <input id="squery" type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search"/>
           <button type="submit" onclick="DoSearch();" class="btn"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
      </div>
</form>
```

I have 3 JS files in my program: this js code in main.js, another js file where I use dataservices.pictureFeedService and dataservices.picturesLayoutService, and one last js file where I only have this:

```
dataservices = {};
```

Comment: Is your input in a form that is actually being submitted and refreshing the page? How do you know it resets itself. How is your dataservices function being called? Why not call it in the function rather than outside.

Comment: _when page refreshes, global variable resets itself._. Yes that is usually what happens to JS variables.

Comment: you don't need to submit form.
remove `type="submit"` from `button`

Comment: Sorry, I included now the full form. I'm calling dataservices like that in another javascript file: dataservices = {}; And debugging my program, I see that after I run DoSearch function, my program execute this dataservices = {} and I lost my search. Sorry, my knowledge about javascript is very poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#custom-search-form button[type="submit"]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    dataservices.pictureFeedService.searchForPictures($('#squery').val(), function (data) {
        dataservices.picturesLayoutService.buildPicturesLayout("images", data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, your solution is good, but you hadn't all the information, it's my fault, I don't know very much about javascript

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) but the [type="submit"] thing isn't necessary, is it?

Comment: It is if you add another button. But in your current markup no.

Answer (score 1):

To stop your page from refreshing, you need to prevent the form submission.

```
    var form;

    // get your form's id
    form = $('#yourformid');

    form.submit(function(event) {
      // stop form from submitting
      event.preventDefault();

      var value;

      // get search term
      value = $('#squery').val();

      // add your code here to do whatever with your input's value

    });
```

Comment: @Razziel, like my first comment on your post. Even if you don't provide an action, a form will submit to the page it's on by default.

Comment: Great solution, this works much better than my Onclick function. Thanks a lot ^^

Answer (score 0):

why not use the onkeyup event of javascript. you can read the value of text box character by character and then use ajax to search your database for the relevant results.

```
function search(){
        var d =document.getElementById('display');
        var a = document.getElementById('txt').value;
        if(a){

        var x = new XMLHttpRequest();

        x.onreadystatechange = function(){

            if(x.readyState==4&& x.status==200){

                document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = x.responseText;
                d.style.display = "block";
            }

        }
        x.open('GET','ajax.php?search='+a,true);
        x.send();

        }else{
            d.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

 </script>
 <style>
    #display{
        border: solid medium black;
        width: 200px;
        display:none;

    }

</style>


<input type="text" id = 'txt' name="keyevent" onkeyup="search();" value="search"    required>Search

<div id="display"></div>
```